# RecyclerView Adapter Attached Skipping Layout, why?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have tried all tutorials to fix my problems but none of them give the solutions. Here is my code :

**Pilih Bus Activity Class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pilih_bus);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    api = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiBus.class);
    Call<ResponseModel> getdata = api.getBus();
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            Log.d("RETROFIT", "RESPONSE : " + response.body().getmKode());
            mItems = response.body().getResult();

            mAdapter = new BusAdapter(PilihBusActivity.this, mItems);
            mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("RETROFIT", "FAILED : respon gagal");
        }
    });
```

I don't know why and where the obstacle is, but let me show you, my adapter class,

**Here is my adapter class :**

```
public class BusAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<BusAdapter.ViewHolders> {

List<Bus> buses;
Context ctx;


public BusAdapter(Context ctx, List<Bus> buses) {
    this.buses = buses;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

public void setmList(List<Bus>mList){
    this.buses = mList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BusAdapter.ViewHolders onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_pilih_bus, parent, false);
    ViewHolders holder = new ViewHolders(layout);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( BusAdapter.ViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    //  holder.dari_id.setText(mList.get(position).getDari_id());
    //  holder.ke_id.setText(mList.get(position).getKe_id());
    holder.class_name.setText(buses.get(position).getClass_name());
    holder.price.setText(buses.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.time_dari.setText(buses.get(position).getTime_dari());




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return buses.size();
}

public class ViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView  class_name, price, time_dari;
    ImageView image;


    public ViewHolders( View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        class_name =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        time_dari = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_dari);




    }
}
```

I got the same problem "no attached adapter skipping layout", and I have already set the adapter.
please help me, thank you in advance

Comment: Just set an empty adapter first, update it as soon as you have the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pilih_bus);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // add below lines here 
     mItems = new ArrayList<>(); // initialize your mItems here
     mAdapter = new BusAdapter(this, mItems); // initialize your adapter with empty mItems
     mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter); // set adapter to your recyclerview like this

    api = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiBus.class);
    Call<ResponseModel> getdata = api.getBus();
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            Log.d("RETROFIT", "RESPONSE : " + response.body().getmKode());

            if(response.isSuccessful()){ // you should check your response is ok or not before doing further action with the response.

                  mItems.clear(); // this will clear all privous data from mItmes
                  mItems.addAll(response.body().getResult()); // add all data to your list
                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this will notify your adapter that your data set has been changed.

            }else{
                 // handle if your api response is not okay
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("RETROFIT", "FAILED : respon gagal");
        }
    });
```

Comment: is it use Firebase? because when I tried, it show message "Firebaseauth is not linked"